# Storing a path for an image file in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am building an application using Codeigniter and am trying to manually store a path to an image file in my MySQL database. The images are stored in a folder called crests which is at root level of the application.

I am using the following code to insert an image into the database but it is throwing up an "Error 1064"

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

/*
File:        crests.sql
Description: Used for creating the objects and loading data into the teams schema
Created:     February 11, 2014
Version:     1.0
Advice:      Save this file onto your hardrive and use the following command(no  semicolon) to run it from the 

command prompt
           SOURCE C:\xampp\htdocs\myApplication\sql_scripts\teams.sql  
*/

SELECT '<starting bars script>' AS '';

SELECT '<my_teams_ database>' AS '';

INSERT INTO teams (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim', '<img src="<?php echo    site_url('../logo/antrim.png'); ?>" 

alt="...">');


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I am getting an error in the MySQL Command Line Client

```
ERROR 1064 <4200> you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server for the right syntax to use near '../logo/antrim.png'); ?>" alt="...">'); at line 1
```

I am not sure if it is a syntax error or if it has to do with escaping quotation marks using a backslash . I am also not sure if this is the correct way to store the path to an image in Codeigniter. I have searched on here and on other forums but cant find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using the MVC to store, manipulate and display this data.

Team Model

```
<?php  
class Team_model extends CI_Model {  

public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
}

function team() 

    {  
        //Query the team table for every record and row  

        $team_results = array();
        $this->db->select('team_name, team_logo');
        $this->db->from('team');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
         $team_results = $query->result();
        }

        return $team_results;   

    }  

}
/*End of file team_model.php*/
/*Location .application/models/team_model.php*/ 
?>
```

In the View

```
<?php

     if (is_array($team_results))
     {
       if( !empty($team_results) ) 
       {

         foreach($team_results as $row) 
         {

          echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">';
          echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<h4>';
          echo '<td>'.$row->team_name.'</td>'."</br>";
          echo '<td>'.$row->team_logo'</td>'."</br></br>";
          echo '</h4>';

          echo '</tr>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
         }
       }

      else echo "Not Array";
    }

    ?>


  </div>
</div>
```

The team_name is returned no problem but the image doesn't display - instead I get a broken image link.

Comment: Are you inserting values or importing from sql file?

Comment: I am importing using an sql file and using MySQL Command Line Client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes or use double quotes:

```
INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim',
      '<img src="<?php echo site_url(\'../crests/antrim.png\'); ?>"  alt="...">');
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim',
      '<img src="<?php echo site_url("../crests/antrim.png"); ?>"  alt="...">');
```

By the way, I would not store an image path like that if I could avoid it (I don't know how you are going to use it...); you would need to evaluate the string that you get from the database later on to process the php.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. This works and gets rid of the error when I am inserting into the database. I am now having trouble with the image displaying when I extract it into my view.

Comment: @emcevoy I can imagine, you'd better store a real path instead of php that needs to be parsed.

Comment: you were right and I now store the path as follows `INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim', '../../crests/antrim.png');` in the database and I  display it in my html as follows `echo '<td>'.'<img src="'."$row->team_logo".'">'.'</td>'."</br></br>";` I used this and it worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with quotation marks used in the insert statement on this line:

```
INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim', '<img src="<?php echo    site_url('../crests/antrim.png'); ?>"
```

The first value is `Antrim`, the next is `<img src="<?php echo    site_url(` and the next single quote terminates this value. After this MySQL expects a comma.

Escape the quotes that are inside the intended values.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. The escape \ work but when I extract and display the value for team_logo in my view the image isn't displayed. I get a broken image link instead - it's like the link doesnt work but if I copy and paste the link directly into the view the image displays no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim', '<img src="<?php echo       site_url('../crests/antrim.png'); ?>"
```

It's not really the best practice to store php or HTML code in a database. Databases are for *data*, not *code*. It would be much better to store just the image path in the DB. You should write your INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo_url, team_logo_altText) VALUES('Antrim', '../crests/antrim.png', '...')
```

And handle any PHP or HTML in the code.

I **REALLY** don't recommend doing this, *but* if you just want to make it work, you can change your query to:

```
INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim', '<img src="<?php echo site_url(\'../crests/antrim.png\'); ?>"  alt="...">');
```

Comment: I am using site_url in Codeigniter - which is a new framework to me. I am trying to manually insert the logos for GAA teams into a database and extract them using a controller and a model - these work for me no problem. Adding escape \ to my code works for inserting the path into the database works but when I extract the data into my view the name appears but the image doesnt show up - I get an alt instead.

Comment: What is the value of the src attribute of the image element when you inspect the it in your browser?

Comment: Thanks for your initial response to my question

Comment: Also, could you post the code where you use this data?

Comment: According to the documentation for `site_url()` (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html), You need to leave off the leading dots: `site_url('/crests/antrim.png')` would point to `http://yoursite.com/crests/antrim.png`

Comment: If I use the following in my view file the image is displayed - `<img src="<?php echo site_url('../crests/antrim.png'); ?>" alt="...">` which shows that the path is ok. I think the problem I have is in using the \ to escape the ' quotation - when I get the image path out of the database the \ is messing up the path i.e `<img src="<?php echo site_url(\'../crests/antrim.png\'); ?>" alt="...">`

Comment: I think if you're doing this much work to get the non-conventional way to work, you should make it easier on yourself and do the more conventional approach I outlined instead. The amount of time you'll save yourself in the long run by doing this will pay off (and whoever else ends up using your DB/app won't be cursing you).

Comment: I have learned over the course of the past few hours that you are right. I was trying to do it using the convention that Codeigniter uses for displaying images using site_urls. I am now doing it using normal file paths e.g. `INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim', '../../crests/antrim.png');` and have it working. Thank you for the advice it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually store a picture path name, for example: images/uploads/[picname].[picext].

so it would be:

```
insert values ('Antrim', 'images/uploads/example.jpg')
```

I find it an easier way to deal with saving path names, you can just handle the img tag through html.

Comment: How do you handle it when you extract it back out?

Comment: I took your advice and store the path as follows `INSERT INTO team (team_name, team_logo) VALUES('Antrim', '../../crests/antrim.png');` in the database and I  display it in my html as follows `echo '<td>'.'<img src="'."$row->team_logo".'">'.'</td>'."</br></br>";` I used this and it worked